# AutoHotKey triggers Ctrl while scrolling

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, scrolling

I'm not sure if this is Windows, Chrome or AHK related so I wanted to post this question.

I've been using AHK for years to make some shortcuts control my volume and media, like Win+PageUp for volume up, Win+PageDown for volume down, Win+End for next track, Win+Home for previous track, etc.

Today I suddenly got the idea to make Win + "scroll wheel up or down" control my volume, for easily turning it way down or way up.

However, when using Win+WheelUp/Down my start menu started flashing open en closed, and Chrome would zoom in or out the page once every so often. I thought switching it to Alt+WheelUp/Down would fix that, and it did fix the start menu flickering, but Chrome is still sometimes zooming in or out when using the shortcut, forcing me to reset the zoom.

As far as I know zooming while scrolling in Chrome is only triggered by holding Ctrl. I've tested and holding Alt while scrolling does not zoom the page. I then tried it in Windows Explorer and using the Alt+WheelUp/Down shortcut also zooms files and folders every so often. Because of this I'm pretty sure it's an AHK issue.

**Does anyone have any idea why AHK is apparently pressing Ctrl every so often and making Chrome/Windows zoom the page?**

Using the latest version, v1.1.30.01

[Also posted on the AHK forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=62282&p=264976)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the AutoHotKey forums I managed to get some answers and fix my issue.

User gregster said:

> Ctrl is the #MenuMaskKey for Alt (and also the windows key).
>
> You can change it. Try #MenuMaskKey vk07 at the top if your script...

But this suddenly opened up a load of "is this a game, want to open gamebar" notifications, freezing Chrome up.

User swagfag said:

> `!WheelUp::Send {Blind}{Volume_Up 2}`
>
> `!WheelDown::Send {Blind}{Volume_Down 2}`
>
> should suppress it too
>
> ah yes, the exact reason why eluded me, but gregster appears to have already posted it
>
> i wonder, though, why was CTRL chosen as the default masking key, and not vk07

That (adding `{Blind}`) fixed it, no more weird side effects from using the shortcut.